# Rails 5 Use form text_field elsewhere in page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, paypal

I have a PayPal form where the user types in an amount:

```
<%= form_with(model: Paypal, local: true, html: {class: 'form-horizontal', id: 'paypal_donate_form'}) do |form| %> 
<%= form.text_field :price_cents, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter Amount (example: 10.00)" %>
```

All I want to do is to insert that amount (that the user has entered) later in the PayPal script on the same page, but I can't quite seem to remember how to do it.

```
 paypal.Buttons({
      env: "#{ENV['PAYPAL_ENV']}",
      createOrder: function(data, actions) {
 
      return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            value: 'FORM_INPUT_VALUE_HERE'
          }
        }]
      });
      
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need some JavaScript. `document.getElementById('idgoeshere').value` would be simplest, if your text field had a unique id.

Comment: Bonus question! Any idea how I would then get that value into my controller? Something Like: "def create_order
    price = document.getElementById('payprice').value" I have a const setup as: "const payprice = def create_order
    price = document.getElementById('payprice').value" in the view... just don't know how to get it into the controller... Thanks.